# How to search and replace some pattern in multiple files at a time?

Tags: perl, replace

I would like to know how can searching a pattern and replacing a pattern can be done in files.I want to write a perl script for doing this.And please explain how I can do it for multiple files.
Thank You...

Comment: -1 for [`plz send me the codez`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16096/can-we-have-a-plz-send-me-the-codez-flag-for-moderation-editor-attention).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you read the [Perl regex tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) first of all.

Comment: I just want the code,a common code that can be embedded and that does the job of searching and replacing.

Comment: I want to replace all instances of the word "design" with "dezine" in the directory /public_html/company/info
I executed the command from document root as
Code:

perl -e "s/design/dezine/g;" -pi.save $(find public_html/company/info -type f)



if you dont want a tmp file you execute the command from directory above as:
Code:
perl -e "s/FIND/REPLACE/g;" -pi $(find path/to/DIRECTORY -type f)                                                                                                                                                      Can you suggest me a better way to perform this operation.

Comment: You could stick that in your question; you could define 'better' (perhaps you want to be able to put it into a Perl script?  I don't know).  Go edit your question and your results will improve.